# What is the Scala equivalent of the `this` operator in Java?

Tags: java, scala, this

In Java I'd normally initialize fields in a constructor in this way:

```
private double real;
private double imaginary;

public Complex(double real, double imaginary) {
    this.real = real;
    this.imaginary = imaginary;
}
```

Is there a way to do the same in Scala for classes or objects? Like instead of

```
class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) {
    def re = real
    def im = imaginary
}
```

something like this:

```
class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) {
    def this.real = real
    def this.imaginary = imaginary
}
```

Edit: whoops, I think I confused methods with fields here.

Answer (score 5):

So far, nobody has directly answered your question.  The Scala equivalent of the Java `this` operator is (surprise!) the Scala `this` operator.  You did indeed confuse methods with fields in your example; your code would work as written if you replaced the `def`s with `val`s.  However, as others have pointed out, you don't need `this` here.

Additionally, Scala allows you to define an 'alias' for `this` using the Explicitly Typed Self Reference syntax that [Peter Schmitz demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450251/what-is-the-scala-equivalent-of-the-this-operator-in-java/5450769#5450769).  The alias 'self' is frequently used, but any identifier is valid.

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double)
```

in Scala you automatically create and initialize fields `real` and `imaginary` so in this case you don't need to use `this`.

Comment: You are thinking about case classes.  For a regular class you would have to do `class Complex(val real: Double, val imaginary: Double)`

Comment: Oh, yes, just overlooked the syntax.

Comment: yes and no. without `val`, there will still be fields, for internal usage: class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) {override def toString = real + " + " + imaginary + "i"}

Comment: @IttayD - I stand corrected.  Doing some experimenting with javap, if you use a constructor parameter **outside** the constructor, Scala will create a private field for it.

Answer (score 2):

For this situation (immutable complex numbers) case classes are exactly what you would want to use.   If you do want to initialize another field in a constructor you would do it like:

```
case class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) {
  val foo = "bar"
}
```

Now real, imaginary and foo are all **public** fields in Complex.

EDIT below -

Using a regular class you can make the constructor parameters public fields like:

```
class Complex(val real: Double, val imaginary: Double)

class MutableComplex(var real: Double, var imaginary: Double)
```

Here is something interesting that I did not know:

```
class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) {
  println(real + " + " + imaginary + "i") 
}

% javap -private Complex
public class Complex extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
  public Complex(double, double);
}
```

`real` and `imaginary` are not in the class.

But if you use the constructor parameters **outside** the constructor, they get added as private vals:

```
class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) {
  override def toString = real + " + " + imaginary + "i"
}

% javap -private Complex
public class Complex extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
  private final double real;
  private final double imaginary;
  public java.lang.String toString();
  public Complex(double, double);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers: You can specify [Explicitly Typed Self References](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124), for example in case of identifier clash.

```
case class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) { self => 
  def +(real: Double, imaginary: Double) = Complex(self.real + real, self.imaginary + imaginary)
}
```

Comment: @Aaron: I don´t know :D I think it´s a valid supplemental to the other answer and shows a new aspect.